# Extract html data from tags using beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have narrowed my objective string to the following html:

```
<h2 class="user-name"> John Kennity <span class="top-class"><a href="http://service-web.com/2008-07-31/11" target="_blank">highest rank </a></span>
</h2>
```

I want to access the name John Kennith. How can I do that in beautifulsoup python ?

Comment: Have you tried `soup.h2.string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bs4

text = '''<h2 class="user-name"> John Kennity <span class="top-class"><a href="http://service-web.com/2008-07-31/11" target="_blank">highest rank </a></span>
</h2>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
name, rank = soup.h2.stripped_strings
```

out:

```
'John Kennity'
```

Comment: If I limit the above scenario to `text = ''<h2 class="user-card-name"> John Kennity </h2>'''` and then use the method `name= soup.h2.stripped_strings` will return `<generator object stripped_strings at 0x000001C5C1FDB830>` But the expected result would be the name `John Kennity`. Is there any difference in applying your approach ?

Comment: @Azfar Faizan `soup.h2.stripped_strings` this will return a generator, you can convert it to list by `list(soup.h2.stripped_strings)`, then you can use index to access the elements in the list.

Comment: @Azfar Faizan `name, rank = generator` is shortcut for `name = list[0], rank=list[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
user_names = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'user-name'})
for un in user_names:
   temp = un.find('h2')
   if temp:
      print temp.text
```